# macOS - interactive/clickable wireframes (adobe fireworks alternative: wireframes feature)

Tags: macos

So [Adobe Fireworks](https://youtu.be/Y3aggLuf62E?si=xT02Cp7n6rFB6doo&t=218) had an interactive wireframe tool. Where you can create hotspots and have the wireframe interact through a browser.

Does anyone know a standalone tool that is support now that does that for the macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Some Prototype solutions:

- Adobe XD, https://helpx.adobe.com/support/xd.html with web export plugin - **maintenance mode**

  - multiple pages support and hotspot navigation
- Axure RP, https://www.axure.com, publish > generate html files - **active**

  - multiple pages support and hotspot navigation
  - Has more than just hotspot clicks as some UI function
- Sketch, https://www.sketch.com, - **active**

  - only image export no prototype local export, only cloud export.